# Links not working when using a JQuery script and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a sidebar using Bootstrap and JQuery. I have written some JQuery code to mark the `<li>` element that was last clicked as active. The sidebar works when my code is commented out. But when I enable it the sidebar no longer redirect to a page when clicked. The highlighting does work though.

JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        "use strict";

        $('ul.nav > li').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

My sidebar:

```
ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./">
                    <span data-feather="home"></span>
                    Dashboard
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <span data-feather="clock"></span>
                    Recently added data
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1">
            <span>DATA</span>
        </h6>
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./applications">
                    <span data-feather="aperture"></span>
                    Applications
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./ships">
                    <span data-feather="anchor"></span>
                    Ships
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">
                    <span data-feather="users"></span>
                    Users
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./containertypes">
                    <span data-feather="anchor"></span>
                    Container types
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">
                    <span data-feather="terminal"></span>
                    Terminals
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">
                    <span data-feather="alert-triangle"></span>
                    Conflicts
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">
                    <span data-feather="box"></span>
                    UNDGs
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="#">
                    <span data-feather="map-pin"></span>
                    Ports
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I am aware some links do not have a reference. This is because those pages don't exist yet. No, I am not trying to go to those pages.
I'm quite at a loss, never really used JQuery before.
Some help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: try to remove             e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `e.preventDefault()` (you will see your item turn active very briefly before getting a 404 :D since the pages don't exist), but you can put an "alert" after changing the style to see that it's actually working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `e.preventDefault();` is stopping the click from propagating to the anchors within the `li` tags.

I tend to update the `active` class once a page has loaded vs prior to following an anchor.

For reference: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/